# Mariadb - How to delete history by query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My Mariadb Version : 10.3.23

Problem: My server's disk is reaching saturation point soon, I got many useless history data in my database.
My table is created with SYSTEM VERSIONING.
I want delete the useless history data by query like below:

```
DELETE HISTORY FROM my_table FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL where my_table.id = 2152
```

I got error message :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SYSTEM_TIME ALL where writing_id= 2152'
```

**Question: How to delete useless historical data associated with a id ?**

Comment: *Problem: My server's disk is reaching saturation point soon* Disk space is cheap right now, simply expand it.

Comment: Keep in mind that any sort of `DELETE` will fail to recoup the disk space.  However, the freed space will be available for future "rows".

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax for deleting useless history is described in [User Manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/temporal-data-tables/#removing-old-history), for example, if you want to remove versions with the age of a month or above use:

```
DELETE HISTORY 
    FROM table_name 
    BEFORE SYSTEM_TIME (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

You cannot delete versioning history for separate rows.

Comment: Simply I can't use "where" with "DELETE HISTORY" ?

Comment: Documentation does not describe such possibility. It allows to delete the whole history, definite partition (except current) or by date only.